# How can we define an XML schema which restricts the value of one element in a sequence of elements of same type?

Tags: xsd

I have an xml which is something like this:

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <value>Fixed value</value>
    </child>
    <child>
        <value>Any value</value>
    </child>
    <child>
        <value>Any value</value>
    </child>
    More children 
</parent>
```

How do I define a schema to check this? i.e. constrain some elements in a sequence of elements to have a child element of a given value. I currently get a warning that the schema is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible since - as the warning states - it makes the definition of the element ambiguous.

**Xml schema doesn't evaluate or validate the content or order of your Xml data, only the structure and data types.**

Comment: The fixed attribute is available and its easy to do something like  this:


   `<parent>
    <child_1>
        <value>Fixed value</value>
    </child_1>
    <child>
        <value>Any value</value>
    </child>
    <child>
        <value>Any value</value>
    </child>
    </parent>`
    
    
So the problem is not the xml is can't validate the value its just an artifact of the syntax I think.

Comment: @Usman Specifying the `fixed` attribute for the element `value` will not let you declare another `value`element without fixed content. You can create an Xml document with such content but you cannot create an Xml schema to validate this.

Comment: Ok, guess this is a dead end then. Thanks